# Using closures to parse two columns of letters

Tags: rust, closures

I have a function that operates on an iterator of Strings with the aim being able to take in a string such as
`A X` and convert that to `(1, 2)`.
The match function is

```
fn convert_throw(c: char) ->  i32 {
    match c {
        'A' | 'Y' => 1,
        'B' | 'X' => 2,
        'C' | 'Z' => 3,
        _ => panic!("Unexpected symbol")
    }
}
```

And the iterator function that does the processing is

```
fn read_throw_pairs(i: impl Iterator<Item = String>) -> (i32, i32) {
    i
        .map(|string| -> Vec<i32> {
            string.split(" ")
                .take(2)
                .map(|element| -> i32 {convert_throw(element.chars().next().expect("Should be char"))})
                .collect()
        })
        .map(|mut item| (item.swap_remove(0), item.swap_remove(0)))
        
}
```

The above function is inspired by this [stack post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231184/rust-code-that-reads-two-columns-of-data-from-txt-file).
I can't get this to compile and I'm not sure what I'm missing.
The error for this function is

```
expected `(i32, i32)`, found `Map<Map<..., ...>, ...>`
```

But using collect() or unzip() also causes issues.

Comment: You have to do something with the iterator, or return an `impl Iterator<Item = (i32, i32)>`, not a tuple.

Comment: How can I just return the tuple? What do I need to do with the iterator? Could I put the tuples into a vec?

Comment: take the first item with `next` or `collect` it or use a `for` to iterate over it or ... It's really not clear what the function is supposed to do, you take a whole iterator of strings, but your description is for a sinlge string only. Or like the example `unzip` it and return `(Vec<i32>, Vec<i32>)` You currently get *several* tuples, you have to decide what to do with them.

Comment: I think by adding another collect() at the end and returning Vec<(i32,i32)> that error is resolved. Now to fix the other bugs.. You helped me realise the mistake thanks!

Comment: While not related, your code indicates that you somewhat see `panic` as the equivalent of `throw` in other languages. Note that this is not what it's for, and it shouldn't be used for that purpose. Use the `Result` type instead.

Comment: @thefrollickingnerd Why not return an iterator? :) Although `Vec` is fine as well, of course.

Comment: @Finomnis I'm only a week into learning rust so still a long way to go! Thanks for the tips